# Custom ImageView loses transparency as soon as it goes out of screen in recycleView

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-canvas

I have a custom ImageView that overrides onDraw method to crop corners using Path to give rounded corner of given radius. I have a RecyclerView where I have these custom ImageView in all of the 4 items. Now the problem is this custom ImageView renders fine for the first time it shows up in the list. Only 2 accommodate in the screen at a time. As I scroll down everything is fine in all views. I can see rounded corner in all of them. But when I scroll up to previous item. Now these corner lose their transparency in corners and become black in all but third item in the list. Canvas in onDraw also has `isOpaque = true`. I have tried many things but nothing seem to be working. Here is the code

```
public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView
{
    private Paint mPaint;
    private int mCornerRadius = 0;
    private boolean mRoundedTopLeft = true, mRoundedBottomLeft = true, mRoundedTopRight = true, mRoundedBottomRight = true;

    public void setCornerRadius(int mCornerRadius)
    {
        this.mCornerRadius = mCornerRadius;
    }

    public void RoundCorners(boolean isRoundedTopLeft, boolean isRoundedTopRight, boolean isRoundedBottomLeft, boolean isRoundedBottomRight)
    {
        mRoundedTopLeft = isRoundedTopLeft;
        mRoundedBottomLeft = isRoundedBottomLeft;
        mRoundedBottomRight = isRoundedBottomRight;
        mRoundedTopRight = isRoundedTopRight;
    }

    public RoundedImageView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
            setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        setupPaint();
    }

    public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
            setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        setupPaint();
    }

    public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
            setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        setupPaint();
    }

    @TargetApi(21)
    public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
            setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        setupPaint();

    }

    private Paint setupPaint()
    {
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(1);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        return mPaint;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Path path = RoundedRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius,
                mRoundedTopLeft, mRoundedTopRight, mRoundedBottomRight, mRoundedBottomLeft);
        canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
    }

    public static Path RoundedRect(
            float left, float top, float right, float bottom, float rx, float ry,
            boolean tl, boolean tr, boolean br, boolean bl)
    {
        Path path = new Path();
        if (rx < 0) rx = 0;
        if (ry < 0) ry = 0;
        float width = right - left;
        float height = bottom - top;
        if (rx > width / 2) rx = width / 2;
        if (ry > height / 2) ry = height / 2;
        float widthMinusCorners = (width - (2 * rx));
        float heightMinusCorners = (height - (2 * ry));

        path.moveTo(right, top + ry);
        if (tr)
            path.rQuadTo(0, -ry, -rx, -ry);//top-right corner
        else
        {
            path.rLineTo(0, -ry);
            path.rLineTo(-rx, 0);
        }
        path.rLineTo(-widthMinusCorners, 0);
        if (tl)
            path.rQuadTo(-rx, 0, -rx, ry); //top-left corner
        else
        {
            path.rLineTo(-rx, 0);
            path.rLineTo(0, ry);
        }
        path.rLineTo(0, heightMinusCorners);

        if (bl)
            path.rQuadTo(0, ry, rx, ry);//bottom-left corner
        else
        {
            path.rLineTo(0, ry);
            path.rLineTo(rx, 0);
        }

        path.rLineTo(widthMinusCorners, 0);
        if (br)
            path.rQuadTo(rx, 0, rx, -ry); //bottom-right corner
        else
        {
            path.rLineTo(rx, 0);
            path.rLineTo(0, -ry);
        }

        path.rLineTo(0, -heightMinusCorners);

        path.close();//Given close, last lineto can be removed.

        path.setFillType(Path.FillType.INVERSE_EVEN_ODD);
        return path;
    }
}
```

What I have already tried: 
 - setting isRecyclable false in ViewHolder

- setting different PorterDuff mode in paint
- LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE (hardware acceleration) for this view
- `setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(0x00000000);` in constructor
- `setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, paint);` passing paint in this function
- tried making canvas transparent before `super.onDraw()`

**UPDATE**:

After a lot of fiddling around I have concluded that whenever my viewHolder's view goes out of screen. All it's alpha channel become black. I have a feeling it has to do something with the `setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);`

Comment: you can set the `attributes` like `radius` and `opacity` in the `onBindViewHolder`

Comment: @Sanoop yeah that would be cool too but I would like to fix this issue first before doing that.

Comment: Yea.. Great. .But try setting the `attributes` in `onBindViewHolder` and check if is recycler causing the issue..

Comment: @Sanoop nope, did not work. Actually I also tried setting `setIsRecyclable(false)` in `ViewHolder`. It was still the same.

Comment: yeah tried setting values in `onBindViewHolder` as well as you said. still same. I have written what all I have tried.

Comment: why dont you simply use a `RoundedBitmapDrawable`?

Comment: @pskink I want to make only top corners rounded. see function `RoundCorners(boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean)`

Comment: so take the sources of `RoundedBitmapDrawable` and modify it so it has only top corners rounded, do you have the sources?

Comment: @pskink `RoundedBitmapDrawable` uses `canvas.drawRoundRect()` to render corners and it only support all round corners.

Comment: then change it  so it uses `canvas.drawPath()` and see `Path#addRoundRect(RectF rect, float[] radii, Path.Direction dir)` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked by making the parent software accelerated.

I solved it by putting

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
                view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

in constructor of my ViewHolder. It worked even if I enabled software acceleration for any parent container view.

Now I don't know why this worked.

Comment: This is because in recycler view  viewholder is attached dynamically and hence the parent to which your view is attached should be software accelerated. Same, goes for hardware acceleration.